# Regression Problem: discretised LSTM+softmax works, but continuous LSTM+Relu+RMSE doesn't

Tags: nonlinear-regression, lstm

I am currently working on a project to calibrate sensors with rate-dependent hysteresis using an LSTM network in tensorflow. The input data's pre-processing comprises filtering for noise + calculation of the gradient (as the major non-linearity comes from the rate of change). These are both then separately normalised (between [0,1] and [-1,1] respectively).

Initially, I discretised the measurement data into ~100 bins, and used classification, mostly because what I was learning from tutorials suited this. I used a 3 layer deep by 270 cell wide LSTM network followed by a linear layer (tf.matmul) on the last prediction (the current data example), softmax regression (tf.nn.softmax), then tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits & tf.reduce_mean. Learning with AdagradOptimizer.

Using this method, I have been getting various good results. I have now tried to alter the network architecture to the more obvious regression problem, and use continuous labels and predictions.

This new model has the same LSTM layers, however the last predictions for that batch, go to a relu layer to allow non-linearity (tf.nn.relu_layer), then a linear layer (tf.matmul), then, tf.losses.mean_squared_error. And learning with AdagradOptimizer.

So I've changed the output to continuous, and [softmax and sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits] to [relu, matmul & mean squared error].

The regression model runs and trains, but the prediction converges to a point, and the loss does not improve.

I would like to know if there is any theoretical reason why this might be the case, as opposed to syntax errors for now.

Thank you very much for your help
Ben